# Logical subscript too long in the context of stepAIC on generalized linear model

Tags: r, glm

I am attempting to develop a model in R that explains the number of walleye harvested (totwal) as a function of a subset of predictors chosen using the stepAIC function from the package MASS. See below for the structure of the dataframe I am using towards this end:

```
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   92036 obs. of  47 variables:
 $ month  : Factor w/ 7 levels "4","5","6","7",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ day    : int  1 2 13 13 13 15 16 16 16 16 ...
 $ year   : Factor w/ 29 levels "1989","1990",..: 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 ...
 $ area   : Factor w/ 9 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ loc    : int  42 13 42 42 31 42 31 42 42 12 ...
 $ dow    : int  5 6 3 3 3 5 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ type   : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 3 2 3 1 3 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ang    : int  3 8 3 6 3 6 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ grid   : int  903 801 903 803 903 804 903 903 903 801 ...
 $ zone   : int  18 10 18 16 18 16 14 12 14 14 ...
 $ seek   : int  334 334 334 334 334 334 334 334 334 334 ...
 $ tis    : num  10 7 6 7.5 9 7 8 7.5 8 6.5 ...
 $ tif    : num  15.5 12 13.5 14 13 15.5 11.5 12 12 10.5 ...
 $ tii    : num  15.5 12.5 14 14.5 13.5 15.5 11.5 12 12 10.5 ...
 $ F1     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F2     : int  5 32 12 24 0 11 8 2 5 1 ...
 $ F3     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F4     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F5     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F6     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F7     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F8     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F9     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F10    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F11    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F12    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F13    : int  0 1 1 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 ...
 $ F14    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F15    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F16    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F17    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F18    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ F19    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F20    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F21    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ F22    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ method : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ WDWE   : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ anghrs : num  16.5 40 22.5 39 12 51 7 9 12 12 ...
 $ X      : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ basin  : Factor w/ 3 levels "east central",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ totwal : int  5 33 13 24 0 11 10 2 6 1 ...
 $ time   : num  12.75 9.5 9.75 10.75 11 ...
 $ TOD    : Factor w/ 2 levels "AM","PM": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ triplen: num  5.5 5 7.5 6.5 4 8.5 3.5 4.5 4 4 ...
 $ effort : num  16.5 40 22.5 39 12 51 7 9 12 12 ...
 $ WAE_POS: num  1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

The main effects I am considering for the model are as follows:

```
f_main_effects <- as.formula(paste("totwal ~ year + month + TOD + ang + triplen + method + WDWE + basin + type + offset(log(effort))"))
```

See below for the model and summary:

```
> res_WAE_poiss <- glm(formula = f_main_effects, data = dat, family=poisson(link="log"))
Call:
glm(formula = f_main_effects, family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = dat)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-13.053   -2.354   -0.815    1.235   36.543  

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       -0.7710820  0.0099014  -77.876  < 2e-16 ***
year1990          -0.3666092  0.0075276  -48.702  < 2e-16 ***
year1991          -0.5909582  0.0079259  -74.561  < 2e-16 ***
year1992          -0.2591255  0.0073414  -35.296  < 2e-16 ***
year1993          -0.0669383  0.0063155  -10.599  < 2e-16 ***
year1994          -0.3658504  0.0070433  -51.943  < 2e-16 ***
year1995          -0.2206199  0.0066573  -33.139  < 2e-16 ***
year1996          -0.1035683  0.0063993  -16.184  < 2e-16 ***
year1997          -0.4919732  0.0072490  -67.867  < 2e-16 ***
year1998           0.1029357  0.0065669   15.675  < 2e-16 ***
year1999          -0.4383308  0.0071890  -60.972  < 2e-16 ***
year2000          -0.4835465  0.0074930  -64.533  < 2e-16 ***
year2001          -0.2362845  0.0077348  -30.548  < 2e-16 ***
year2002          -0.4938362  0.0076850  -64.260  < 2e-16 ***
year2003          -0.3045370  0.0083361  -36.532  < 2e-16 ***
year2004          -0.1870754  0.0067665  -27.647  < 2e-16 ***
year2005           0.0084350  0.0074392    1.134    0.257    
year2006           0.1609717  0.0063515   25.344  < 2e-16 ***
year2007           0.0352623  0.0068963    5.113 3.17e-07 ***
year2008          -0.1079411  0.0077131  -13.995  < 2e-16 ***
year2009          -0.2403672  0.0082776  -29.038  < 2e-16 ***
year2016           0.2797565  0.0061268   45.661  < 2e-16 ***
year2017           0.7801561  0.0057861  134.834  < 2e-16 ***
month5             0.2492277  0.0071682   34.769  < 2e-16 ***
month6             0.5002337  0.0069455   72.022  < 2e-16 ***
month7             0.5930889  0.0070208   84.476  < 2e-16 ***
month8             0.4875154  0.0074904   65.086  < 2e-16 ***
month9             0.3895295  0.0086433   45.067  < 2e-16 ***
month10            0.1483472  0.0108386   13.687  < 2e-16 ***
TODPM             -0.1060913  0.0024875  -42.650  < 2e-16 ***
ang               -0.0328293  0.0008702  -37.726  < 2e-16 ***
triplen           -0.0924310  0.0006020 -153.527  < 2e-16 ***
method2            0.2659051  0.0027271   97.506  < 2e-16 ***
WDWE2             -0.0662235  0.0020664  -32.048  < 2e-16 ***
basinwest          0.3995765  0.0036221  110.316  < 2e-16 ***
basinwest central  0.1031291  0.0038891   26.518  < 2e-16 ***
type2              0.2337072  0.0032363   72.214  < 2e-16 ***
type3              0.5876307  0.0038143  154.060  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 865844  on 79916  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 602809  on 79879  degrees of freedom
  (12119 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 863541

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

I then attempt to use stepAIC to select a subset of predictors considering second order interactions and constraining it to always include year and effort.

```
res_WAE_pois_step <-  stepAIC(glm(totwal ~ year + offset(log(effort)), data = dat, family=poisson(link="log")), scope=list(upper = totwal ~ (year + month + TOD + WDWE + method + basin + ang + triplen)^2 + offset(log(effort))), direction = "forward", trace=5)
```

This results in the following error:

```
Start:  AIC=1119511
totwal ~ year + offset(log(effort))

Error in x[good, , drop = FALSE] : (subscript) logical subscript too long
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this error in the given situation. It may also be worth mentioning that the same script functioned correctly on a dataset that shared an identical structure but had fewer observations. Does anyone know what could be causing this error or have suggestions for how I could remedy it? Please let me know if more information would be useful, but I cannot legally share the data.

Thank you for your time and help.

UPDATE:
The problem has been solved. WDWE values were NA in years 2010-2015 when they should not have been, and I was able to update the dataframe with the complete data and the script once again runs fine. That said, could someone help me understand 1) why the glm function would silently drop those years instead of throwing an error? and 2) how do I understand the error I received from stepAIC based on this new information? Is the error also a result of those years being silently dropped?

Comment: Can be related to differences in the number of factors. Try convert year and month to numeric. Also see if a GLM is really the best way to analyze your data.

Comment: Thanks, Carlos. The GLM shown is just an example of the problem - same problem occurs with ZINB models. The decision to have those variables as factors is a conscious one based on what else has been published on the topic and our theoretical understanding of their relevance - so it may be inappropriate to treat them as continuous numeric, unless I am misunderstanding the suggestion.

Comment: The 'drop = FALSE' part of the error message suggest that the problem can be differences in the number of factors. Test that converting all factors to integer or character.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. Converting those columns to numeric resulted in the same error. Even after converting all columns to numeric the error remained the same.